# NoModuleName 'channels', but I have installed it. Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

Django version 2.1.5
Channels version 2.1.6
Ubuntu 18.0.4

**When I run project in pyCharm, it says:**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.

<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f18ecd8eb70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/mercer/venv_linux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels'
```

**The module installed**

```
(venv) mercer@mercerPC:~/Documents/comet$ pip list | grep channels
channels 2.1.6
```

**Here is the installed_apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'chat',
    'accounts',
    'events',

    ...

]
```

Also I created the routing file and added `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see in your stack trace the python environment is called: `venv_linux`, where you're executing  `pip list | grep channels` in another one called `venv`.

That's your problem.

Comment: I've changed it for better understanding. But as i can see, it was wrong. And i solved my problem, I had wrong python interpreter in configuration. Thanks for suggesting